Change gender in jannah and marry my cousin
I want to change my gender in jannah... is that possible to change our gender in jannah? I don't support LGBTQ..I have decided that I will not commit any sins in this world that would make Allah displeased with me, and I will keep Allah happy in this world so that I can go to heaven. In heaven, I want to change my gender and marry my cousin. Is it possible to change my gender in heaven and marry my cousin?

What you are asking for is considered completely unnatural (against fitrah) in Islam and so will never be accepted by Allah SWT

There is no mention of people changing gender in Jannah, so you should assume that this is not possible.
This is also beneficial for your present life: You should try to master to reject your desire and accept that you will not be able to marry your cousin in Jannah. If you manage to master those feelings, with God's help, you may ask for, there are no obstacles to be with your cousin, if not, you would have to restrain from him/her (isn't clear whether you are both male or female).

But miracles are performed by Allah... someone told me that in the hereafter we won't have these bodies, rather Allah will create us anew... so why isn't it possible that our gender could change as we desire, because we lived our lives in this world according to Allah's will, so why wouldn't Allah listen to us in heaven?

I can't say and I didn't say that such is definitely impossible, just that it's not mentioned anywhere. I think it will be helpful to you to leave that thought because of the life here and now.

I am not saying that I want to become transgender in this world and marry my cousin, rather I am saying that if I become pious here and follow all of Allah's commands, then should I pray to Allah regarding this matter? Because it is not so easy to leave this thing... leaving someone is very difficult, especially controlling one's feelings... so it is not that easy for me to completely forget this topic right now.. so this thing bothers me a lot, that's why I am asking here if someone has any information about this matter, please let me know.

My concept would be to leave the thought of marriage, which would make it easier for you to direct your feelings and be able to be together with your cousin in a normal way.

But this is not the place for personal advice.
